# MAGENTO : Wrong attribute group ID

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I need some help how can I solve this error, im installing the extension ERP.

```
 Error in file: "/app/code/community/MDN/Purchase/sql/Purchase_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.2.0.php" - Wrong attribute group ID
 #1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.1.0', '2.8.6.6')
 #2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.1.0', '2.8.6.6')
 #3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
 #4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
 #5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
 #6 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 #7 /index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
 #8 {main}
```

this is the code for **mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.2.0.php**

```
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','default_supply_delay', array(
                                'type'      => 'int',
                                'visible'   => false,
                                'label'     => 'Default Supply delay',
                                'required'  => false,
                                'default'   => '5',
                                'global'       => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                                'note'      => 'In days'
                                ));

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','supply_date', array(
                                                        'type'      => 'datetime',
                                                        'visible'   => false,
                                                        'label'     => 'Supply date',
                                                        'required'  => false,
                                                        'global'       => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE
                                                        ));


$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add group key in array and provide name of the group of attribute

```
  'group' => 'Test Group',
```